# Custom resampling of data in lists

Tags: python

I need help resampling OHLC data stored in lists without using the pandas `resampling` function. (i.e. resampling 1 hour to 4 hour frequency)

Example of the data structure:

```
data = [ [100, 200, 50, 150], [100, 200, 50, 150], [100, 200, 50, 150], [100, 200, 50, 150]]
```

The most recent interval is `data[0]`.

Comment: Most here who know how to resample OHLC data will probably not know how to do it without pandas. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks but it shouldnt be too difficult to iterate the list for the open high low and close.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
new_data = random.sample(data, 2)
```

You will have to make sure that number of samples is lower than the original data list length.

Another option is to use `numpy` ;)

```
import numpy as np
new_data = np.random.choice(data, 2)
```